# When use Desktop Computer Android Emulator Blurred Text Problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I was previously developing mobile applications on a laptop, but now I am switching to a desktop computer. When I run the emulator, I see that the texts are blurred.
I'm afraid this will cause confusion while developing.Do you have a solution suggestion?

Resolution: 1920x1080
23.8 inch

[image]